# how to repeat a process in a specific order?

Tags: java

I want to make the program print for any integer that I input an asterisk in such way that every new line there is an increasing number of two more asterisks, always starting from one asterisk.

This code will print for any integer the same number of lines that I entered, with one asterisk in it, but how do I increase the number of the asterisks in each line?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number:");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int j=0;
    int star=1;
    int space= num; 
    System.out.println ("* ");

    if (num>0) {
        for (j=1; j<num; j=j+1) {
            System.out.println ("* " );
        }

        for( j=0; j<star; j++) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question looks like homework to me. While asking homework questions is perfectly fine, there are some good guidelines for asking homework questions here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812). Summarized, they are: make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first; ask about _specific_ problems with your _existing_ code; let us know that the question is homework; make sure your class allows using Q&A for help; don't copy and paste an answer's code without first understanding what it does and how it works.

Comment: it is a question as given homework, but i modified it cuz i want to understand rather than just ask here for an anwer

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "* "; // let's use a variable for the next line we want to print
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number:");
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    if (num > 0) {
        System.out.println(line);
        for (int j = 1; j < num; j++) { // j++ does the same as j = j + 1
            line = "*" + line; // add a * at the start of the line
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to consider using a `StringBuilder` instead of using String concatenation in a loop.

Comment: Indeed. But he seems to be a beginner, so this will be easier for him to understand :-)

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).  `PrintStream` has a second method, [`print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-) that prints out what you put but without printing out the end of line character after it.

So, you probably want to use that instead.

Now, having said that, you'll still need to print out the end of line character when you've finished with the other characters.  You can do that by calling the [no argument version of `println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--) (which looks like `System.out.println();`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for something like this:

```
INPUT: 4
*
**
***
****
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.Print("*");
    }
    System.out.Println();
}
```

Note that this prints out only one star at a time, and will be fairly slow.  Fun to watch though, if toss a sleep statement in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two for loops for that, one for lines and another for stars.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    System.out.Print("*");
 }
System.out.Println();        
}   


Output:
=======
*  
**  
***  
****  
*****
```